# C# WPF React to a clicked button in another method

Tags: c#, wpf, button

Sorry if this is a basic question but somehow I have not been able to find a good answer to what I thought would be something very simple.

In one window I have a textblock, a textbox and a button (and some other items). The textblock has a question and you are supposed to enter the answer in the textbox. After entering the text you press the button to check if the answer is correct. The questions are handled in a foreach loop in method A. In "the middle" of the loop I need to check if the answer was correct. After searching I only found the following solution. Is this really the "correct way" of doing this?

I am quite new to C# so maybe I am overseeing something. The method seems to work but I would have expected something like a "wait for button pressed".

Any ideas or links to information would be very welcome ... Thanks a lot

```
TaskCompletionSource<bool> tcs = null;

private async void goingThroughTheList()
{
    foreach member of the list
    do something
    tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>();
    await tcs.Task;
    do something
}

private void button_method(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   do something
   tcs?.TrySetResult(true); // this triggers that the other method
                      // knows that the button has been pressed
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Wouldn't it be easier for the button to invoke the second part of your "goingThroughTheList()" if the first part has been completed?

```
bool FirstPartDone = false;

private void FirstPart()
{
    foreach (var item in list)
    {
        // do something
    }
    FirstPartDone = true;
}

private void SecondPart()
{
    foreach (var item in list)
    {
        // do something
    }
}

private void button_method(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    // do something
    if (FirstPartDone)
    {
        SecondPart();
    }
}
```

Comment: Haky, thanks for your suggestion. But that doesn't work in this case. I have a part in the code where I need to wait for the button pressed.